# Integration of Codepen code in ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to integrate the following code in my ionic project from codepen, but cant understand in which files I have to copy the js,css files. I tried copying it app.js but it crashes. Moreover do I have to edit any code or just the same codepen will work.

Here is the pen: [Codepen](http://%60http://codepen.io/rossmartin/pen/XJmpQr%60)

Comment: Your link does not work.

Comment: http://codepen.io/rossmartin/pen/XJmpQr

Comment: You have to copy JS section into 'app.js', CSS section into 'style.css', the copy HTML section into 'index.html' file adding in it the reference to app.js (`<script src="app.js"></script>`) and style.css (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />`). The pathname of app.js and style.css depends on where they are located inside the **www** folder of your Ionic project.

Comment: You can also check this Plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/e0E9DpllpusOva64K51V) in which I edited the Codepen you linked. Plunker is easier to adapt in a real project as it has explicit reference to project files (app.js, ...). It is possible to download the project too.

Comment: I want to write a template in ionic